# Item description and sums missing in paypal express checkout approval page

Tags: node.js, paypal

I am using paypal REST API to test out express checkout on sandbox environment.

Everything works fine except one thing: order description area is rather empty: no summs, no individual item information, no total order sum amount - I can see only my dummy description" regardless that I do pass order summ amount.

I am passing payment information similar to one used in the example apps:

```
var ppPayment = {
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {},
    "transactions": [{
        "amount": {
            "currency": "EUR",
            "details": {
                "subtotal": 0
            }
        }
    }]
};

ppPayment.transactions[0].amount.total = params.req_order_amount;
ppPayment.redirect_urls.return_url = "http://xxxxxxxxx/confirm?order_id=" + order_id;
ppPayment.redirect_urls.cancel_url = "http://xxxxxxxxx/cancel?order_id" + order_id;
ppPayment.transactions[0].description = "Dummy description";
ppPayment.transactions[0].amount.details.subtotal = params.req_order_amount;
```

What lines should I add to the payment.create call to user to be able to see the description like displayed here [image: normal order]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the API

[PayPal REST API Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#transaction-object)

You need to create `transaction object` inside which `item_list object` consisting of items. Lets name one `item object` or and go by your screenshot :

1. `paypalItem.name`
2. ..until 6. : See API for `item object`. Some fields only exist in `invoice_item object`
3. ..until 10. : See API for `Invoice object`

Good luck

Comment: Great! cannot image how I've missed it!

Answer (score 0):

So the explicit answer will be :

```
ppPayment.transactions[0].amount.total = params.req_order_amount;
ppPayment.redirect_urls.return_url = "http://xxxxxxxxx/confirm?order_id=" + order_id;
ppPayment.redirect_urls.cancel_url = "http://xxxxxxxxx/cancel?order_id" + order_id;
ppPayment.transactions[0].description = "Dummy description";
ppPayment.transactions[0].amount.details.subtotal = params.req_order_amount;
ppPayment.transactions[0].item_list = 
          {
            items: [{quantity: 1, name: 'My stuff', price: params.req_order_amount, currency: "USD"}]
          };
```